# How can you set the HTTP protocol version in Postman?

Tags: web-services, http, post

I need to specify HTTP 1.0 in a POST request via Postman. It defaults to HTTP 1.1. Does anyone know how to specify the version of the HTTP protocol, or am I out of luck?

Comment: See https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/6242

Comment: I created a HTTP testing tool with support for HTTP/2 and HTTP/3. It has full compatibility with existing Postman collections and environments.
https://github.com/alexandrehtrb/Pororoca

Comment: @Alexandre it is not available on mac?

Comment: @Alexandre But http2 only available for linux and windows

Comment: Update (2022-09-21): Pororoca now supports HTTP/2 requests on Mac OS. @Stan

Answer (score 40):

Unfortunately, it's still not supported by Postman as of April 2019. Previous version of Postman used to be a browser extension and it wasn't possible to fine tune the request. Newer versions, however, run as standalone applications which could allow more low-level control of the request.

See the following comment quoted from the issue [#6242](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/6242) which was opened early April 2019 requesting an option to specify HTTP protocol version:

> You'll be pleased to know that work is in progress for more low-level control over the request. Stay tuned.

As of December 2023, however, Postman still haven't shared any updates on this.

---

Depending on what you need, you could use [curl](https://curl.haxx.se). It provides a set of options that allows you to control the version of the HTTP protocol:

- [`--http0.9`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--http09): Tells curl to be fine with HTTP version 0.9 response.
- [`-0`, `--http1.0`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-0): Tells curl to use HTTP version 1.0.
- [`--http1.1`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--http11): Tells curl to use HTTP version 1.1.
- [`--http2-prior-knowledge`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--http2-prior-knowledge): Tells curl to issue its non-TLS HTTP requests using HTTP/2 without HTTP/1.1 Upgrade. It requires prior knowledge that the server supports HTTP/2 straight away.
- [`--http2`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--http2): Tells curl to use HTTP version 2.

Comment: Frankly speaking I didn't catch difference between 2 last options

Comment: @gstackoverflow Let me clarify the `--http2-prior-knowledge` usage: When the client knows the host supports HTTP/2, the client can connect directly by sending a HTTP/2 connection preface. There's no need to start a HTTP/1.1 connection and then upgrade to HTTP/2.

Comment: So '--http2' requires upgrade from 1.1?

Comment: @gstackoverflow Yes. Once curl relies in nghttp2 for HTTP/2 support, I recommend you check [this page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/http2.html) for reference.

Comment: These comments reflect curl behavior, not official browser HTTP behavior, btw. Upgrading from HTTP/1 to HTTP/2 has been deprecated for security reasons.

The current standard is HTTP/1 for insecure connections, and the use of ALPN during TLS to negotiate which version of HTTP to use for secure connections. Requesting upgrades may fail, depending on the server.

Answer (score 13):

Apparently this is not supported by Postman. There has been a report for this on the project's Github page ([issue](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/876)), but it doesn't look like this is gonna be implemented any time soon.

There are a couple of alternatives that support HTTP protocol version for Rest and Soap testing:

- [Tosca Testsuite](http://www.tricentis.com/tricentis-tosca-testsuite/): Tosca includes Webservice testing for Soap and Rest. Setting the HTTP protocol version can be done in the [Webservice TestCase creation](https://documentation.tricentis.com/en/841/index.htm#tbox/wse_testcases.htm%3FTocPath%3DTBox%7CWebservice%2520Engine%25203.0%7CCreating%2520Webservice%2520TestCases%7C_____0).
- [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/): SoapUI also supports [setting the HTTP protocol version](http://www.soapui.org/working-with-soapui/reference/preferences-and-settings.html)

Comment: checked with the latest open-source version of SOAP UI. In Http settings, I can only see HTTP1.0 and HTTP1.1. There is no option for HTTP2.
is there any other tool?

Answer (score 3):

Not supported as of this date. You can try to copy the curl code by clicking on the **Code** link, and run it, specifying the http version by passing --http parameter to curl.

[image]

For example, to run curl in Windows 10, replace the single quotes with double quotes:

```
curl --http2 --location --request GET "https://myrequesturl...." --header "myTestHeader:test" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data-raw "{"query":"","variables":{}}"
```